# HTMLStripCharFilter is not working in createComponent implementation of Custom Analyzer

Tags: java, lucene

I have used HTMLStripCharFilter in createComponents implementation of Custom Analyzer implementation but HTML is not stripping from the content. Please find below the code.

```
@Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) 
    {
        StandardTokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer();
        source.setReader(mStripHTML ? new HTMLStripCharFilter(getReader()) : getReader());
        source.setMaxTokenLength(maxTokenLength);
        TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(source);
        result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CharFilter shouldn't be defined in your createComponents methods, it should be in initReader:

```
@Override
protected Reader initReader(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    return mStripHTML ? new HTMLStripCharFilter(reader) : reader;
}

@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) 
{
    StandardTokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer();
    source.setMaxTokenLength(maxTokenLength);
    TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(source);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks..However, I got the solution in lucene documentation yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use CustomAnalyzer instead: https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/custom/CustomAnalyzer.html

(it is available since Lucene 5.x)